# Ruby on Rails route for wildcard subdomains to a controller/action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I dynamically create URLs of the form `username.users.example.com`:

```
bob.users.example.com
tim.users.example.com
scott.users.example.com
```

All of `*.users.example.com` requests should go to a particular controller/action. How do I specify this in `routes.rb`?

All other requests to `www.example.com` go to the normal list of routes in my `routes.rb` file.

***UPDATE***: I watch the [railscast about subdomains](http://railscasts.com/episodes/123-subdomains-revised) and it showed the following bit of code which would seem to be exactly what I need (changed the controller and subdomain):

```
match '', to: 'my_controller#show', constraints: {subdomain: /.+\.users/}
```

The problem is it only matches the root URL. I need this to match EVERY possible URL with a `*.users` subdomain. So obviously I would put it at the top of my `routes.rb` file. But how do I specify a catch-all route? Is it simply `'*'`? Or `'/*'`?

Comment: This railscast might help you : http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3?autoplay=true

Comment: rails 3 rails 3.2 rails 4 hmhmmmm... which one exactly? just as a side-note, if you plan to have a lot of javascript, than keep in mind that ajax across subdomains is a PITA.

Comment: @phoet - I should've been more clear with the Rails versions. I'm using 3.2, but would upgrade to 4.0 if it meant this solution would be easier.

Comment: my recommendation would be: don't do it. but the railscast that @AmitThawait pointed you to is a perfect example. you can also have a look at a multitenacy example here: https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/blob/master/config/routes.rb#L30

Comment: @phoet - what do you mean don't do it? Don't create my app that I want? Is there another solution?

Comment: @at. i would build an app that uses paths instead of subdomains whenever possible. there are so many constraints with cookies, javascript and ssl when it comes to domains...

Comment: @phoet - I need this because we sometimes need to change the DNS to point to a different system for individual users. The cookies/javascript/etc won't be an issue for my situation.

Comment: @AmitThawait - I watched a newer version of that Railscast, thanks. Updating my question based on it.

Comment: @at. if you look at the code i linked or the answer of @Amit you see that `constraints` is used to do exactly that.

Answer (score 9):

I think, you just need to do the following :

create a class `Subdomain` in `lib` :

```
  class Subdomain  
    def self.matches?(request)  
      request.subdomain.present? && request.host.include?('.users')
    end  
  end
```

and in your `routes` :

```
constraints Subdomain do
  match '', to: 'my_controller#show'
end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can constraint route dynamically based on some specific criteria by creating a `matches?` method

Lets say we have to filter sub domain of URL

```
constraints Subdomain do
  get '*path', to: 'users#show'
end

class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    (request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain.start_with?('.users')
  end
end
```

What we are doing here is checking for URL if it start with sub domain `users` then only hit `users#show` action. Your class must have `mathes?` method either class method or instance method. If you want to make it a instance method then do

```
constraints Subdomain.new do
  get '*path', to: 'proxy#index'
end
```

you can achieve same thing using `lambda` as well like below.

Instead of writing class we can also use `lambdas`

```
get '*path', to: 'users#show', constraints: lambda{|request|request.env['SERVER_NAME'].match('.users')}
```