# how to allow user to add html and javascript in my rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, security

I want to create a Rails app where users can create their blog in a subdomain like : `user1blog.myapp.com`, `user2blog.myapp.com` etc...

I want to allow users to add html and javascript (sometimes they need to add popups to their blog, or tracking code ...)

I see a lot of website which allow users to add scripts and html without any restriction, but How i can do that too without affecting the security of my Rails app ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple facets to this question:

**Dynamic Subdomains**:

Other questions address this:

[Rails 4 Dynamic Subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885271/rails-4-dynamic-subdomains)

[Ruby on Rails route for wildcard subdomains to a controller/action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359260/ruby-on-rails-route-for-wildcard-subdomains-to-a-controller-action)

short answer, there are many ways and it depends on your use case.

**User submitted html, js**

There are many solutions here as well.

I Suggest searching for "CMS" (Content Management System).

There are solutions like refinery, Comfy Mexican Sofa, and others.
Again, it depends significantly on your use case.

**Security of my Rails app**

If you are allowing user submitted html and js, I would say that you are implicitly compromising the security of your site. Your Rails app itself might be securable, but that's a major thread of conversation about xss, auth[z/n], and other items. Again, highly dependent on your use cases.

Comment: I know about subdomains but i don't think they resolve the security issue !! each time you say dependent in my use cases !!! I think my use case is very simple : find any type of solution to be secure and in the same time allow users to save javascript & html code. how sites like blogger and thumblr do ?

Comment: The problem is "the security issue" isn't identified in your question. What issue(s) are you worried about?
For example, as a trivial case (that isn't good) - why can't you allow a form that allows arbitrary upload of files, with a text field for "subdomain"?

Comment: I don't specify an exact issue because I don't know about all the possibilities of attacks, but the main thing is preventing a user to get access to another user account, also i will have an admin area in my main domain which i won't other users to get access too...

Comment: also there is a monthly subscription, and i want the system to be secure enough !  I am open to all kind of ideas and suggestions...

Comment: In the meta section of this site (http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ) : "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." This comes close to that domain. I would suggest that you show what you've tried, what you expect, and how your current efforts/tech is insufficient in a specific manner, rather than a broad question such as this.

Comment: you can take a look at other question like this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530811/how-to-allow-users-to-write-javascript-with-security?rq=1  you may call it "broad" too, but there are people who answer, anyway it's a pleasure to talk to you, thanks!